# Proof of Lemma 2.5.22, Liu's Alg. Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm struggle understanding the last statement below from Qing Liu's "Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves".

> Lemma 2.5.22 (pg. 73): Let $A$ be a finitely generated integral domain over $k$, and let $p$ be a prime ideal of $A$ of height $1$. Then $\dim A/p=\dim A-1.$

Proof. Let $f\in p\backslash \{0\}$. Then $\sqrt{fA_p}=pA_p.$ As $A$ is Noetherian, there exists an $h\in A\backslash p$ such that
$$\sqrt{fA_h}=pA_h.$$

My question: Why such an $h$ exists? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal $p$ is finitely generated, say $p=(y_1,...,y_k)$. Since $\sqrt{fA_p}=pA_p$, there exists some $n\geq 1$ such that $\frac{y_i^n}{1}\in fA_p$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$. This means for each $i$ there exists some $u_i\notin p$ such that $u_iy_i^n\in fA$.

And now let $h=u_1u_2...u_k$. Note that for all $i$ we have $hy_i^n\in fA$, and so $\frac{y_i}{1}\in\sqrt{fA_h}$ in $A_h$. Since the elements $\frac{y_1}{1},...,\frac{y_k}{1}$ generate $pA_h$ over $A_h$, it follows that $pA_h\subseteq\sqrt{fA_h}$. The other inclusion is easy.